# How can I use a variable in a relational algebra query?

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

I have the following [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkAAF.png).

I would like to find the following in a query:

The sailor names for sailors who reserve **ONLY** the boats that Brown reserves (Meaning only Brown and Blake should show up, as they are the only ones solely reserving Boat 1 and Boat 4 in the Reservation table).

I have tried the following, and have even used a [relational algebra calculator](https://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc.htm#) however I am stuck. I am able to get to the point where all rows in the table include the correct boats, however I don't know how to exclude the entries with extra boats on top of that. All help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
X = π SN, BN (Reservation) ⨝ π SN, Name (Sailer)
Y = π SN, BN (Reservation) ⨝ π BN (Boat)
Z = X ⨝ Y

CONTAINING = π Name, SN, BN (Z) / π BN (σ Name = 'Brown' (Z)) ⨝ Z
LAST = CONTAINING - π SN, BN, Name (σ Name = 'Brown' (Z))
RESERV = γ Name; count(Name)->NUM_RESERV (CONTAINING)
π Name (σ NUM_RESERV = NUM_RESERV RESERV)
```

This produces:

```
Sailer.Name:
Smith
Blake
Brown
```

Comment: Please use text, not links/images, for text, including tables & ERDs. Please read hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & explain your code, including what you think is correct & what you are stuck with. We don't know what youi think your subexpressions calculate, so how can we know where you went wrong? Please give a [mcve] in code questions--including relational algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sketch of a solution:

1. let `reserved-by-brown` the table consisting of the BN of the boats reserved by Brown; this can be found by joining the three tables with a restriction on sailor name and a projection on BN.
2. Let `sails` the table obtained by the division of projection on SN and BN of Reservation by the table `reserved-by-brown`. This produces the SN of the sailors who have *at least* reserved all the boat reserved by Brown.
3. Let `non-brown` the table obtained with the difference from the projection of Boat on BN and `reserved-by-brown`: this contains all the BN of boat *non* reserved by Brown.
4. Let `non-brown-reservation` the join between `non-brown` and `reservation` on the attribute BN. This contains all the reservations without those of boats reserved by Brown.
5. Finally, compute the difference between sails and the projection on SN of the previous table `non-brown-reservation`. This will contain the desired result.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. It was the extra difference operations that I should have looked more into. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Renzo; this trick of expressing an 'only' or a 'equal all' as a difference-of-a-difference is standard in RA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Division_(%C3%B7), as Codd (1972) explained for division. And I guess it's persisted because that double-negative is how you must do it in SQL, as usually a double-`NOT EXISTS`. But really it's a terrible way to express it in an algebra that's supposed to be based on set theory: you should be able to compare sets (i.e. relations) directly, with a subset test.